# React hooks useEffect call API second time and first time calling API response also returning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm fetching API with useEffect and API responding correct like

```
{response: {message: "This is a image link", status: "success"}, error: null}
```

Second time when I'm receiving next API call response and If there is a error then old response is not removing. It's showing like this

```
{response: {message: "This is a image link", status: "success"}, error: TypeError}
```

I worked [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-custom-usefetch-react-hook) tutorial code for fetching API

Check my exact code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-taussig-lj01m)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  console.log("useFetch");
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const FetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
        // console.log("json - ", json);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log("error - ", error);
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    FetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return { response, error };
};

function App() {
  const API_URL = `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`;
  const [apiUrl, setApiUrl] = useState(API_URL);
  const res = useFetch(apiUrl, {});
  console.log("res - ", res);
  if (!res.response) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const apiCallAgain = () => {
    const apiUrl = `https://d.ceo/api/breeds/image/q`;
    setApiUrl(apiUrl);
  };
  const dogName = res.response.status;
  const imageUrl = res.response.message;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={apiCallAgain}>API Call</button>
        <h3>{dogName}</h3>
        <div>
          <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

open console and check `res` object by default. Now click on `API Call` button and check `res` object again. When I'm using useState `null` in starting then why old state is showing?

Comment: Please add the relevant code here, so that it can be solved even without using a third party service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a component rerenders, hooks do not reinitialize all state in them. State cannot not work if that were the case (component re-renders when you change state).

Instead for each render, `useState` hook stores and returns it's specific value for that render. In your case when the `API_URL` changes, `useEffect` reruns, but the state variables don't.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> This is a way to “preserve” some values between the function calls —
>   useState is a new way to use the exact same capabilities that
>   this.state provides in a class. Normally, variables “disappear” when
>   the function exits but state variables are preserved by React.

A fix for this would be to reset the state for response and error in `useEffect`:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    setResponse(null);
    setError(null);
    const FetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
        // console.log("json - ", json);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log("error - ", error);
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    FetchData();
  }, [url]);
```

Comment: My experiment shows that `setResponse(null)` and `setError(null)` is not called the second time.

Comment: @Elye Didn't get you.. can you elaborate?

Comment: I call `useFetch(myUrl, option)` once, and it works. The second time it is called, it doesn't work anymore, and just get back the same result. Did I use hooks wrongly?