# React.js: useState Hook Setter is not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to update the state conditionally to trigger visibility.

However when I pass a initial value to the useState hook, it updates only once.

**Code 1**: Updating only once when there is an initial value

```
const ImageRef = useRef(null);

// Initial Value Passed
const [isHidden, setShown] = useState(true);

const _HandleShown = () => {
    const nextState = window.scrollY > ImageRef.current.offsetHeight;

    if (isHidden !== nextState) {
        setShown(nextState);
    }
};
```

**Code 2**: Working as expected when there is no initial value

```
const ImageRef = useRef(null);

// No Initial Value Passed
const [isHidden, setShown] = useState();

const _HandleShown = () => {
    const nextState = window.scrollY > ImageRef.current.offsetHeight;

    if (isHidden !== nextState) {
        setShown(nextState);
    }
};
```

Comment: it's looks like this question, updates single time only, Please check once https://stackoverflow.com/q/57296445/2129071

Answer (score 0):

I guess `_HandleShown` is use in `addEventListener...`, in that case you want to use `isHidden` to compare you need to do this, because of closure in JS.

```js
const ImageRef = useRef(null);

// Initial Value Passed
const [isHidden, setShown] = useState(true);

const _HandleShown = () => {
    const nextState = window.scrollY > ImageRef.current.offsetHeight;

    setShown(prevIsHidden =>{
      if (prevIsHidden !== nextState) {
        return nextState
      }
      return prevIsHidden
    });
};
```