# Firebase fetching error in react-native with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, use-effect

I have an error when fetching data from a doc in firestore to react native

I use useEffect to do this, and only run it once. The problem is, the first time I run the query it returns Empty (I set up a console log to check this). However if I remove [] from useEffect and let it run infinitely, on the 2nd run it fetches the data.

Could this be a firebase problem or with my code? And how could this be solved? Should I try to run useEffect 2 times? How is that done?

```
useEffect(() => {
    
firebase.firestore()
.collection("allPosts")
.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
.get()
.then((snapshot) => {
    let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return { id, ...data }
    })
    setPost(data)
})

 if (post[0]?.field) {
     console.log(post[0].field)
 } else {
     console.log('Empty')

    
 }
}, [])
```

Comment: I found an example of using firebase firestore in react native here https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage. have you tried it?

Comment: the array ```[ ]``` inside useEffect function perform as the parameter that calls useEffect function. so if the array is empty, than the useEffect would be called once after the component is rendered.

Comment: I think I found the same case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296445/react-hooks-useeffect-call-api-second-time-and-first-time-calling-api-response-a

Answer (score 0):

You should use the key instead of the firestore field value in the where a check of the firestore query.

like :

```
const postId = props?.route?.params?.postId

useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore()
        .collection("allPosts")
        .where('id', '==', postId)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return { id, ...data }
            })
            setPost(data)
        })
}, [postId])
```

- Make sure that the key name exists in the firestore document.

Comment: Tested it, still the same result. In the 2nd query it works, in the first doesn't fetch anything

Comment: May I know, What do you mean by the 2nd query?

Comment: based on that code, and [] at the end of useEffect, it only performs one query. However, if I remove that [] at the end of useEffect, It performs the firebase fetch infinitely. And the first function returns empty, however 2nd and all other functions fetch the right data.

Comment: My goal is to know if this is a problem in firebase, my code, or I should simply let useEffect run 2 times which returns data successfully

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a try with it

Comment: Still the same result. Runs only once, and returns empty

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with fetching data in one of my projects. Putting the id as a listener in square brackets like so seemed to fix it for me (I also added an extra if statement to check if I was actually getting the right id)

From what I understand the useEffect only runs once the id has been fetched

```
const id = props?.route?.params?.postId

   useEffect(() => {

if(id!=null){
   
firebase.firestore()
.collection("allPosts")
.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
.get()
.then((snapshot) => {
    let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return { id, ...data }
    })
    setPost(data)
})

 if (post[0]?.field) {
     console.log(post[0].field)
 } else {
     console.log('Empty')

    
 }
}else{
console.log("id not found");
}
}, [id])
```